# Selecting Rows for a particular ID where columns corresponding to that have only mentioned set of values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table as follows:

```
ID  | Value  | Other Columns...........| .......
-----------------------------------------------
ID1 | Value1 | ....................... | .......
ID1 | Value2 | ....................... | .......
ID2 | Value3 | ....................... | .......
ID3 | Value4 | ....................... | .......
ID3 | Value4 | ....................... | .......
ID3 | Value5 | ....................... | .......
ID4 | Value4 | ....................... | .......
ID4 | Value5 | ....................... | .......
ID5 | Value2 | ....................... | .......
ID5 | Value4 | ....................... | .......
ID5 | Value5 | ....................... | .......
```

The Value column can have 5 types of values : Value1 through Value5.
I need to write a query where I should get all IDs where Values are only 
**Value4** and **Value5**. Example: **ID3** and **ID4**.
As I am new to SQL, how should I go about it in an optimized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  A simple way is:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when value = 'value4' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value = 'value5' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value not in ('value4', 'value5') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The conditions are counting how many times the `value` is each of the values for a given `id`.  The `> 0` says that at least one row has the value.  The `= 0` says that no rows with the `id` have the value.

Comment: Works like a charm! +1
It would be even more helpful if you explain a bit more on : 
       having sum(case when value = 'value4' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value = 'value5' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value not in ('value4', 'value5') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Just I am giving you a rough idea of the query .

```
Select * from table where value is value or value 4
```